# Foreach undefined variable error on codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, foreach, undefined

I have this error in my view and can't find out what is the problem.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: c

Filename: views/commentsList.php

Line Number: 10
```

Here is my view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="commentsByParentId">
   <?foreach($comments as $c):?>
        <?=$c['comment']?>
    <?endforeach?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`$comments` is array coming from controller. `$c` is loop variable, so i can't understand why it is catching **undef var error**.

UPD: here is my controller code

```
public function viewCommentsListByParentId($parentid) {
    $data = array();
    $data = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comment')->findBy(array('parentid' => $parentid));
    $comments = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
        $comments[$i]['comment'] = $data[$i]->getComment();
    }
    $this->load->view('commentsList', $comments);
}
```

Comment: post your array structure

Comment: You'll want to see if $comments array actually has any data in it. Try doing a `print_r($comments);` before the forloop.

Comment: show the controller code and it´s a lot easier to solve the problem

Comment: Do you need to add spaces between code and tags when using short tags? You do with normal ones, i.e. `<?phpecho'test';?>` will not work.

Comment: @Ziinloader, i posted my controller code

Comment: `$data['comments'] = $comments;
$this->load->view('commentsList', $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your server allow `<?` tags. Some configurations don't and they'll turn them into regular html comments. Try `<?php foreach($comments as $c): ?>`, see if that removes the problem.

Edit:

Now that we fixed that error, it doesn't know what $comments is. That's because in your controller you defined it as $commentsList:

So you need `<?php foreach($commentsList as $c): ?>`

Note: You still can't use `<?` tags, because those were the problem in the first place.

Second Edit:

I looked up CodeIgnitor's documentation, and it says you have to include in `$this->load->view('view_name', $data);` where data is an array of values, where the key is the variable name used in the view, and the value is the value of that key.

So try this: `$this->load->view('view-name', array('comments' => $comments));`

Then in the view go back to `<?php foreach($comments as $c): ?>`

See [this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) for details

Comment: would that not do the same thing for the `<?=` line too then, not generating any error?

Comment: Probably worth switching them all to the normal versions, just to be sure.

Comment: Generally <?= is allowed but <? is not. I tried running the code on my machine, and I was confused the $c wasn't defined. Then I found that it had commented out the <? tags, but not the <?= tags. Some machines do this, it depends on your php configuration.

Comment: yourdeveloperfriend, i tried <?=, but the result the same

Comment: @Grace You misunderstood my post. The `<?=` is not the problem, but you may need to replace `<? foreach($comments as $c): ?>` with `<?php foreach($comments as $c): ?>`

Comment: i tried to replace with <?php foreach($comments as $c): ?>, but then i have undefined variable $comments

Comment: I saw your edit. Now see my edit.

Comment: @yourdeveloperfriend, i don't see any changes. What is your edit?

Comment: @yourdeveloperfriend, ok, i see, but commentsList is a view name, not a variable

Comment: Sorry, I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your controller code:
You need to pass $comments in an associative array to view:

```
$data['comments'] = $comments; 
$this->load->view('commentsList', $data);
```

Comment: I tried. Result is the same. undefined variable c

Comment: ok then, do a `print_r($comments);exit;` just before foreach and check the output

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [comment] => new comment 1 ) [1] => Array ( [comment] => new comment 1 ) [2] => Array ( [comment] => new comment 1 ) [3] => Array ( [comment] => new comment 1 ) [4] => Array ( [comment] => new comment 1 ) [5] => Array ( [comment] => wqwq ) [6] => Array ( [comment] => wqwq ) [7] => Array ( [comment] => fd ) [8] => Array ( [comment] => fd ) [9] => Array ( [comment] => fdsadfdsf ) [10] => Array ( [comment] => fdsadfdsf ) [11] => Array ( [comment] => one more comment ) [12] => Array ( [comment] => dfgsgdsfg ) [13] => Array ( [comment] => one more comment ) )

Comment: That's strange... it should work with your code.
try @yourdeveloperfriend's solution replace every tag with <?php and <?= with <?php echo $c["comment"]; ?>

Comment: i tried, but then i have undefined variable $comments message

Comment: I updated my answer after looking at your controller code, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
foreach($comments as $c){
    echo $c['comment'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange error you got there. Why use the shorthand PHP tag when there is no HTML in the foreach loop? Or is the production code different?

You can make your code work by using the following code (work-around):

```
<?php
    foreach($comments as $key=>$c) {
        if(isset($c) && isset($c['comment'])) {
            echo $c['comment'];
        } else {
            echo 'Error at index ' . $key;
        }
    }
?>
```

Please report how manu errors you get returned.

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: comments

Filename: views/commentsList.php

Line Number: 11

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/commentsList.php

Line Number: 11

Comment: Uhhh the foreach has an invalid argument? Very strange.. The `$comments` is an array right? Because the `$key=>$c` thing is correct PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: i answered my own question with solution of problem

Answer (score 0):

Everybody, thank you. I solved the problem this way. I changed my controller to this. It seems better to pass controller array of objects than array of arrays.

```
public function viewCommentsListByParentId($parentid) {
    $data = array();
    $data['comments'] = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Comment')->findBy(array('parentid' => $parentid));
    $this->load->view('commentsList', $data);
}
```

and changed my view to this

```
   <?php foreach($comments as $c):?>
        <?=$c->getComment()?><br>
    <?php endforeach?>
```